# How to add overflow-x: hidden to react js on mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set `overflow-x: hidden` on my react app, I have set it on the index.css body, it works on desktop screens, but not on mobile, I read the best way would be to add it to the parent element, but it doesn't seem to work on React, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to wrap all your elements in a div for example and apply the `overflow-x: hidden` on it.

You can also try to use media queries and apply the `overflow-x: hidden` on the body of your app. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```